# SQL - correctly use constants instead of table name in FROM clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm working with soem code to find the product of two numbers in sql.  I'm following [this](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/the-aggregate-function-product/) tutorial's example.  What I would like to know is, what is the correct syntax to use when a list of constants is used in a select statement's FROM clause instead of a table name?

E.g.

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(num))) as product
FROM (VALUES (2),(3),(5),(7),(11),(13)) as NUMS(num)
```

This example keeps throwing the error

> 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.'

Again, I'm assuming this is possible, I'm just not sure what the correct syntax is.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax is valid for SQL Server 2008+. You must be running against an earlier version.

Try it as:

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(num))) AS product
FROM (SELECT 2 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 7
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 11
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 13) AS NUMS(num)
```

Comment: Thank you Joe and everyone else, I neglected to mention I was working with SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got to define your NUMS table using a UNION

Such as:

```
    SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(NUMS.num))) as product
    FROM
    (
    select 2 as num
    UNION
    select 3
    UNION
    select 5
--you get the idea...
    ) as NUMS
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be some shorter way but this certainly works:

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(num))) as product
from
(
select 2 as num
union all
select 3
union all
select 5
union all
select 7
union all
select 11
union all
select 13
) NUMS
```

Answer (score 0):

[Table Value Constructors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) are new to SQL Server 2008. If you're trying on SQL Server 2005, they won't work.